# JS: put all obj's keys together as each new element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
const dataArray = [
    { keyA: ["valueA1", "valueA2"] },
    { keyB: ["valueB1", "valueB2"] },
    { keyC: ["valueC1", "valueC2"] },
]
```

Put all obj's keys together as each new element and match inner array's elements with their respective index order.

The inner array's values are always fetched in the same index's order.

the following **intended result** explains better what I mean:

```js
[
    {
        keyA: "valueA1",
        keyB: "valueB1",
        keyC: "valueC1",
    },
    {
        keyA: "valueA2",
        keyB: "valueB2",
        keyC: "valueC2",
    }
]
```

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far and what you're getting stuck on.

Comment: Well, I have the length of each inner array (in the example is two). Plus, I am trying to get each keys with Object.keys by iterating them. But I think there is a better way. And I still don't match the result.

Comment: It would be good to add that to your question so that we can help show you what you may have done wrong (it also helps show others that you've put in effort to solve your question before you decided to post a question :))

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```js
const dataArray = [{
    keyA: ['valueA1', 'valueA2']
  },
  {
    keyB: ['valueB1', 'valueB2']
  },
  {
    keyC: ['valueC1', 'valueC2']
  },
];
const keys = dataArray.map((data) => Object.keys(data)[0]);
const result = [];

let keyIndex = 0;
let valueIndex = 0;

while (valueIndex < dataArray[0].keyA.length) {
  const obj = {};
  for (keyIndex = 0; keyIndex < keys.length; keyIndex++) {
    obj[keys[keyIndex]] = dataArray[keyIndex][keys[keyIndex]][valueIndex];
  }

  result.push(obj);
  valueIndex++;
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I was trying with similar reasoning, but stuck. This `for loop` and `valueIndex` ultimately nails it. Thanks!